# Calculate voltage and current in an op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

Hi I have a op amp circuit that i need help in calculating some values (see image, Å=A in further description)

[image: OP amp cicuit]

The values i have are:

```
                  RF =  0.4 kΩ

                  RA =  70 kΩ

                  Ri =  0.14 kΩ                          

                  RL =  0.7 kΩ
```

So for E= 100 mV what are a) Uut and b) IA ?

I have tried doing Uut=E*F=E*(-RA/(RF+Rk/2))=-6.363 V which was wrong. I thought it was a differential op amp, so i found the F formula in the book, but i don't know if that is correct to use here.

Comment: Homework, I guess?

Comment: Yes:/ And i am a beginner in elecrical assignments

Comment: Do you think it would be fair if we give you a solution here? Or will help you in learning?

Comment: I have tried everything...And teachers dont respond during summer. Ill add what i have tried doing so it might lead me in learning.

Comment: This is the right approach. People on SE respect questions showing own effort.

Comment: Hint: the voltage at the inverting and non inverting inputs will be the same.  Post your workings we are happy to help but we need to see your attempt first

Comment: I just posted the attempt i have made!:)

Comment: Do not apply formulas without thinking - use Warren's hint- what is the input current? And how does that relate to Ia and Uut?

Comment: Also, since the common mode voltage (E- to ground) is not given, it presumably is not important. By the same token, then, you can set it to whatever is convenient, like 1 volt, and than calculate voltage at the inputs. If you do this and get a solution, try again with a different voltage, like 2 volts, and see if the solution changes. If it does, you know that the problem is badly presented.

Comment: Okey, so the voltage is the same at both inputs, i think E since they share the source. Also i know that there is no current going in to the amp. So one idea also is to use kirchoffs rules to follow the voltage from Uut to E. So that would be Uut = IA*RA+IA*RF+IA*Ri+E but then IA is not known. Am i on the right path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make things easier for me explain, you have two Ra in the circuit. I will call the lower Ra in the schematic as Ral and the upper as Rau, ok? And I will call the node that connects Ral, Rf and the non-inverting pin of the opamp as V+ and the node which connects Rau, Rf and the inverting pin as V-, ok?
So, when the opamp have feedback, it will do everything it cans to make the voltage at V- and V+ to be the same value. It is sometimes called as a "virtual short-circuit". With that in mind, you can imagine a single network made on by E, Ri, Rf and the other Rf, all in series. In such circuit, is pretty easy to calculate the current that will flow through E, Ri and both Rf, right? I will call that current as Ix. 
Assuming that the opamp is ideal, no current will flow trough the opamp pins. So, you can see that Ix will flow through Ral, and with that information you can calculate the voltage across Ral, right? So, you can calculate the voltage at V+, as one pin of Ral is in the ground (the reference), so V+ has the same value as the voltage across Ral, ok?
Remeber that V- and V+ have the same value? So, if you know the value of V+, you know the value of V-. Can you see that Ix will flow through Rau, since there is no other path to it? Can you see that the value of Ia is -Ix? By knowing the value of Ix, can you calculate the voltage across Rau? If you know the voltage of V- related to the reference, can you calculate the voltage on the other pin of Rau related to the reference? Sure you can. And that voltage is... Uut.

I hope now that circuit is easier to understand than my horrible english :)

Comment: Okey, thanks for the description i followed it and understand a lot of it.So i have now gotten to the part where i found the voltage across Rau. But then i dont really get the last part, what do you mean by "If you know the voltage of V- related to the reference, can you calculate the voltage on the other pin of Rau related to the reference?" Since that helps me fins Uuot it is an important part.

Comment: Ok, you know the current across Rau, right? That current is Ix. So, you can calculate the voltage across Rau, is: Vrau = Ix * Rau, right? You know the voltage of V- related to ground, which is the voltage across Ral, is it clear? The value of V- is the same of V+, since there is a "virtual short circuit" between the pins of the opamp input. So, you know the voltage related to ground of the pin of Rau that is connected to V-. Lets call that pin of Rau as pin 1. Lets call the other pin of Rau (that is connected to the opamp output) as pin 2. (will continue on the next message).

Comment: By definition, the voltage across Rau is the difference of the voltage os both pins. It means, Vrau = Vpin1 - Vpin2. What do you know about those variables? You know Vpin1 (which is V-, which is V+, which is Vral), and you know Vrau (which is Ix * Rau), so it is pretty easy to calculate Vpin2, right? And voila: Vpin2 is the voltage of the output of the opamp, which is... Uut!

Comment: Nice, give me a vote :)

Answer (score 0):

Classic differential amplifier. Resistors \$R_F\$ and \$R_A\$ connected to non-inverting and inverting inputs of-amp are the same, respectively, so the simplest way to calculate output voltage shall be:

$$
V_{out} = \frac{R_A}{R_F} \cdot (V_+ - V_-)
$$
$$
V_{out} = \frac{70k\Omega}{0.4k\Omega} \cdot -0.1V = -17.5V
$$

But... there is internal resistance of voltage source \$R_i\$ which is in series with resistor \$R_F\$ connected to non-inverting input, so we need to use a full equation for differential amplifier, and assume that \$R_{Fi}\$ is a sum of \$R_F\$ and \$R_i\$:

$$
V_{out} = \frac{(R_A + R_{Fi})R_A}{(R_A + R_F)R_{Fi}} \cdot V_+ - \frac{R_A}{R_{Fi}} \cdot V_- 
$$

In above equation \$V_+\$ and \$V_-\$ are potentials referenced to ground. To obtain theme You should remember that both inputs of an op-amp are considered to be on ground level all the time. So \$E\$, its internal resistance and \$R_F\$ resistors create simple circuit with common current flowing through them. This current is:

$$
I_E = E / (R_i + R_F + R_F) = 0.1V / (0.14 + 0.4 + 0.4)k\Omega \approx 106.4{\mu}A
$$

Voltage drop at \$R_F\$ is:

$$
V_{R_F} = I_E \cdot R_F = 106.4{\mu}A \cdot 0.4k\Omega = 42.5mV
$$

So potential \$V_+\$ (connection point of lower \$R_F\$ and \$E\$) is \$-42.5mV\$, referenced to ground. And potential \$V_-\$ (connection point \$R_i\$ and \$E\$) is \$57.5mV\$, \$100mV\$ higher than \$V_+\$.

Now, we know everything:

$$
V_{out} = \frac{(70k\Omega + 0.54k\Omega)70k\Omega}{(70k\Omega + 0.4k\Omega)0.54k\Omega} \cdot -42.5mV - \frac{70k\Omega}{0.54k\Omega} \cdot 57.5mV \approx -12.97V 
$$

Current flows through the \$R_A\$ is:

$$
I_A = V_{out} / R_A = -12.97V / 70k\Omega \approx 185.3{\mu}A
$$

As [user1521378](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/80698/user1521378) suggest You can also assume that \$V_-\$ will be at connection point of upper \$R_F\$ and internal resistance of \$E\$, then You should calculate potential at this point in the same manner like for \$V_+\$ and use first simple equation to obtain output voltage.

Comment: Why V+ - V- = -0.1v? Voltage on the positive terminal is 0.1v*Ra/(Ra+Rf).

Comment: @ilkhd Read entire answer, in first step I assume that internal resistance of source E is negligible, and then I try to explain it should be taken into consideration.